# Label individual points with ordiplot3d?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

Is there any way to add individual point labels in an ordiplot3d plot? Example using package data below.

[image: 3D plot of the data]

```
library(vegan3d)
library(ggplot2)


data(dune, dune.env)
SITE_ID <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t")
dune.env$SITE_ID <- SITE_ID
ord <- cca(dune ~ A1 + Moisture, dune.env)
ordiplot3d(ord)
pl4 <- with(dune.env, ordiplot3d(ord, col = Management, pch=16,angle=50))
with(dune.env, ordihull(pl4, dune.env$Management, draw = "poly", col = 1:4,label=T,
                    alpha = 50))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work!

```
sp <- scores(pl4, choices=1:3, display="sites", scaling="symmetric")
spp <- as.data.frame(cbind(dune.env$SITE_ID,sp))
with(dune.env, ordilabel(pl4,labels=spp$V1,col="black", fill=NA, border=NA))
```